# Cleanly extract homemade candle from glass or plastic mold?

Tags: wax

I have a melted-crayon decorative candle idea, but I can't figure out the last step.

The concept is based on melting crayons using the sun & foil, to create art or new crayons.

Instead, I want to melt crayons inside a small glass, ceramic or plastic container (preferably glass or even ceramic), such as a shot glass. I will warm up the container with a candle warmer or a beverage warmer plate.

My issue will be removing the formed candle after it's melted as desired. I don't think it'll just pop out once cooled.

Is there a way I can easily remove the wax, keeping the form intact? Or, is there a way to prep the container beforehand?

I should be able to test this on existing small candles or tealights we have that are in glass, but it will be some time before I can test other container materials.

(I don't know if there are different "types" of wax. If there are, please advise what type crayons typically are.)

Comment: Erm, "wax" for candles can be different things and "wax crayons" as well. While the stuff used in candles *should be tested and ok to burn*, this is probably not true for crayons. I personally wouldn't risk it or at least use beeswax-based crayons - which are ridiculously expensive.

Comment: @Steph I've seen that emergency crayon candle life hack, but I was planning on using these for decoration, not burning

Comment: Ah. Good! Just wanted to clarify...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wax and Glass have very different rates of thermal expansion. Once the liquid wax has cooled and become solid, and you don't think the glass is at a risk of shattering, I would suggest putting the wax filled mold in the freezer. The wax should just pop loose. If it doesn't a quick rinse of the glass in warm water should release the wax.

This trick also works for wax on tablecloths, napkins, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wax will often shrink a bit while cooling down so with a bit of luck the candle will come out fairly easy. Otherwise you can warm the mould carefully until the candle slides out.